# Why doesn't Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool appear to do anything?

Tags: c#, .net, objectpool

Using Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool v7.0.11 and running the following statements in LINQPad v7.7.15

```csharp
var pool = ObjectPool.Create<object>();
var thing = pool.Get();
pool.Return(thing);
pool.Uncapsulate()._items.Dump();
```

The result is

```
ObjectWrapper<Object>[47] = { null, null, null, null, null, null, ... }
```

Shouldn't I be seeing the object in the internal list of items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're messing around with undocumented internals of the ObjectPool.  Looks like there's an optimization for the case where a single object is checked in and out frequently, and it's assigned to a field `_firstItem` instead of being added to `_items`.

[image]